# Different behaviors for different user levels

Tags: permissions, sudo

I'm using an application which I can install plugins.

When I don't open the application with sudo I can't install those plugins, but when I open the application with sudo, I can.

I don't want to open the application every time using sudo, I just want to login in my user and open the application and work on it. What do I have to do?

Comment: We can help if you can be more specific with a program (or couple of programs) you're having problems with.  What you described is most likely the results of having run various applications as `sudo` and now your normal account don't have access to the configuration files.  If you name the programs you're having problems with we can tell you how to fix the specific permissions for those applications.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment indicating your problem, you have been running applications under `sudo` which is giving ownership of files in your personal space to root.

You added an answer, which may have been your attempt to respond to the my comment.  Your question suggested that you have a number of applications that you are having problems with.  You can cure all the problems with two command lines.

You can **verify and see which files are not owned by you** with this command line:

```
$ find ~/ -mount ! -user $(whoami)
```

**You can take ownership of the files in your space** with:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/
```

Those two command lines will fix all the permissions you have for all your applications.

Answer (score -1):

I just fixed the problem.

I was trying to install a theme in the program named Brackets, it's an IDE I like to write HTML.
Every time I tried to install a theme, the Brackets gave me an unexpected error, so, I tried to do the same thing opening the Brackets in the Terminal with the sudo command, and it worked very well, I could install the theme.
The problem is I did not like to open Brackets with sudo command every time.
I found where Brackets installs the plugins, that is, the directory where Brackets installs the themes, and I gave permission to my user to this directory.

Please, let me know if this is enough.

Thanks !

Comment: That's what I mentioned to you in my comment for more details.  People often will ask the person providing the answer in a comment to put the working resolution in an answer so that they can accept it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: Hello folks, 

So, I've tried to be simple as much as I could to ask this question.
But I will edit my answer to be more specific and help others.